# Play youtube/vimeo video embedded in HTML in Android WebView

Tags: android, video, webview, youtube, vimeo

Hey So I'm trying to play youtube/vimeo videos embedded in HTML inside of a `webview`.

The typlical HTML will look like this:

```
<p>Here's some text from a server</p>
<p>This text goes inside of a webview</p>
<p>Sometimes there are iframe's with vimeo videos embedded in the HTML text like this:</p>

<iframe src="//player.vimeo.com/video/12345?title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0" width="500" height="281" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>

<p>Sometimes there are iframe's with youtube videos embedded in the HTML text like this:</p>

<p><iframe width="640" height="360" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/-NwibJy9-Cg?feature=player_detailpage" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></p>
```

But no video plays, and no thumbnail for the video is shown either.

I've looked at many different StackOverflow posts on this subject but have not found any luck with them.

Here's my code to set up the webview:

```
public class ReaderFragment extends Fragment {

private TextView mTitleTextView, mDateTextView;
private WebView mContentWebView;
private StoryItem mStory;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
                         final ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_reader, container, false);

    mTitleTextView = (TextView) v
            .findViewById(R.id.fragment_reader_story_title);
    mTitleTextView.setText(mStory.getTitle());

    mDateTextView = (TextView) v
            .findViewById(R.id.fragment_reader_story_date);
    mDateTextView.setText(mStory.getAuthor());

    mContentWebView = (WebView) v
            .findViewById(R.id.fragment_reader_story_content);

    mContentWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
    mContentWebView.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
    mContentWebView.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON_DEMAND);
    mContentWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    mContentWebView.setBackgroundColor(0x00000000);
    mContentWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    mContentWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mContentWebView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    mContentWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);

    //I load the webview with the entire HTML content from the server, including text, and
    //sometime <iframe> videos, I'd like to successfully embed these videos!
    mContentWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, mStory.getUnparsedContent(),
            "text/html; charset=utf-8", "UTF-8", null);

    return v;
}
```

How can I display these inline `<iframe`> videos within my `WebView`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So after a couple of days tinkering with this I **FINALLY** found the solution to my problem!

If you want to play `<iframe ../>` videos within your `WebView` you **NEED** to load the data with a base URL! This baseURL should be the URL of where the video is embedded, or anything to help indicate where the video can be found.

**DONT** do this:

```
// You need to give a baseUrl (e.g. the corresponding url of the HTML String)
webview.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, htmlWithVideosString,
            "text/html; charset=utf-8", "UTF-8", null);
```

**DO THIS INSTEAD**:

```
    /*
     VERY important to supply a baseURL for playing the videos!
     Without a baseUrl the WebView has no idea where to look for the video.
     The baseUrl will typically just be the URL that corresponds to the 
     HTML String that you are using.
    */
    mContentWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL(baseUrlOfHtmlContent, htmlWithVideosString,
            "text/html; charset=utf-8", "UTF-8", null);
```

Good Luck!

Also remember to set up your `WebView`...Like so...

```
    mContentWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
    mContentWebView.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
    mContentWebView.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON_DEMAND);
    mContentWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    mContentWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

**TIP**: May need to turn "hardware acceleration” on in the `Manifest` for this to  work.

**Example** Hardware Acceleration On:

```
<application
    android:name="com.example.app"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true">
<!-- hardwareAccelerated requires SDK 14 -->
...
</application>
```

Comment: It's just the name a variable in my project... But that argument is the string that will be loaded into the webview.

Comment: what does `StoryItem.getUrl()` return ?

Comment: What if, the HTML is `String youtubeHTML = "<html><body><iframe width=\"100%\" height=\"100%\" src=\"http://www.youtube.com/embed/vWZ2W86JkME?rel=0\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe></body></html>";` and is then loaded with `WebView.loadDataWithBaseURL("https://www.youtube.com", youtubeHTML, "text/html; charset=utf-8", "UTF-8", null);` What's the correct URL for that ?

Comment: I can't tell for sure, but probably the youtube url. Or whatever the url is for the video you are loading.

Comment: This solution did not work for me on android 2.3. Is the APIs have issues with this version? Could anybody explain more on the parameters to loadDataWithBaseURL() specifically 1st two? I could not find much on this over internet.

Comment: Yes the minSDK version is 14. Because you need to turn hardwareAcceleration on in the manifest, which is only available on SDK 14 and above.

Comment: Worked. Thank you!

Comment: @Dexter, `Android 2.3 (9)` is very very old, even at the time of your comment it was old. You’ll see that the answer says you may need to turn on “hardware acceleration” in the `Manifest`, which is only available on API `14` and above. The answer goes over `loadDataWithBaseURL()` and it’s parameters, with examples, not sure what else you want.

Comment: Thanks Sakiboy, I got the ans. This does not work for 2.3 API. API v14 above required.